# Buzzbox Task wont run Android

Tags: android, task

Using the Buzzbox SDK for Android, and the simple examples.

The task wont run.

The activity launches, the buzzbox schedule is set, it is saved.

```
ScheduleManager.getInstance().saveTask(this, */1 * * * *", RobotTask.class);
ScheduleManager.getInstance().restart(this,RObotTask.class);
```

The Task: Well, it is just like the example. There is nothing wrong with the code.

I need to DEBUG the TASK, or somehow find out how or why Buzzbox does not launch tasks and does not work.

Using eclipse is the Buzzbox scheduled task de-buggable?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. I was confused last night. But after a good sleep the answer was clear.

Make sure the AndroidManifest.xml contains the same as the buzzbox helloworld example.

In particular,

The receiver SchedulerReciever part in the manuifest
must be defined.

The intent-filter, lists 'actions' that can be received.

This is the thing that receives 'actions' from Android and buzzbox .

The 'action' that triggers your task is called com.buzzbox.mob.android.scheduler.wakeup
for example.

Now that the receiver and the action are defined in the Manifest as per the example..

It is all working so beautifully.